# Grouping hour intervaled data into averages per day

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

## Problem

The database contains a Delivery table with ***three columns:*** *id*, *start time*, and *finish time*.

The start and finish columns are of the timestamp without time zone data type (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

I want to write a query that generates a table with ***two columns:*** *day* and *average time to deliver*.

## Example

Delivery table example:

```
| deliveryid |         start        |        finish        | 
+------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|      1     |  2021-12-03 02:00:00 |  2021-12-03 03:00:00 |
|      2     |  2021-12-03 06:00:00 |  2021-12-03 08:00:00 |
|      3     |  2021-12-04 15:00:00 |  2021-12-04 16:00:00 |
```

Desired result from the query using above example:

```
|     day    |  average  | 
+------------+-----------+
| 2021-12-03 |  01:30:00 |
| 2021-12-04 |  01:00:00 |
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please add example data and the expected result to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `::date` to extract the date and then use this in `group by`.

> ```
> select 
>   *,
>   finishing - starting time_difference
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> starting            | finishing           | delivery | time_difference
> :------------------ | :------------------ | -------: | :--------------
> 2022-05-07 08:00:00 | 2022-05-07 10:00:00 |        1 | 02:00:00       
> 2022-05-07 12:00:00 | 2022-05-07 16:00:00 |        2 | 04:00:00
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   starting::date "date",
>   AVG(finishing - starting) average_time
> from t
> group by starting::date
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | average_time
> :--------- | :-----------
> 2022-05-07 | 03:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=61631eb8d12e2c0c4b5424e89e6d4ffa)*